# Go back after Searching with setActionView in Android using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

With this code (taken from ABS examples) I'm able to add a "Search" icon in my ActionBar which will display an EditText when clicked (to search in a list):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, searchId, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_search)
     .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
     .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
     .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    return true;
}
```

With this code I'm able to show a different layout after tapping the "Search" icon:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case searchId:
        search = (EditText) item.getActionView();
        search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        search.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        this.allSongs = data.getSongs();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songList);
        list.setAdapter(new SongAdapter(this, this.allSongs));
    }
    return true;
}
```

With this code I'm able to handle my search:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        List<Song> results = new ArrayList<Song>();

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        for (Song song : allSongs) {
            if (song.getTitle().toLowerCase(locale).contains(s.toString().toLowerCase(locale)))
                results.add(song);
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songList);
        list.setAdapter(new SongAdapter(ctx, results));
    }
};
```

When the user taps the "Search" icon, the EditText appears in ActionBar and the App Icon gains the "back" left arrow.
If the user taps "Back" button or taps the ActionBar icon (with left arrow), the EditText disappears.
I'd like to intercept this event (no, onOptionsItemSelected() doesn't fire this time) and show the previous layout, in addition to hiding the EditText.

Note: I need API8 (Android 2.2) compatibility!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an *ActionView*, tapping "up" or "back" doesn't result in an *Ancestral Navigation* (which can be handled by *onOptionsItemSelected*) but results in a *Collapsible Action event*.

Found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) on Android Developers.

> **Handling collapsible action views**
>
> If you need to update your activity based on the visibility of your
> action view, you can receive callbacks when it's expanded and
> collapsed by defining an OnActionExpandListener and registering it
> with setOnActionExpandListener(). For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionItem);
    ...

    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when expanded
            return true;  // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
}
```

So, to answer to my question, I was searching for onMenuItemActionCollapse event.

PS: for better consistency I should move my *case searchId:* from *onOptionsItemSelected* to *onMenuItemActionExpand*

Answer (score 0):

For the Home button, can I assume that you called

```
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

when setting up the Sherlock Action Bar in onCreate()? I believe that's required in order to get onOptionsItemSelected() callbacks with an item ID of android.R.id.home when the home button is clicked.

For the back button, I think you just need to override onKeyDown in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: No, I have not called `.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` because at the `onCreate()` of my Activity I don't need the "home" button, I need it only when searching (to undo the search).
It shows up by itself due to `.setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)`, I think.